# What can I include with the constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I am working on my first Java program as a piece of homework. The task is to have a cataloging program to store and manipulate some products.

I have two classes, a catalog class and a product class. The product class stores data about my products (ID, Price, Color). The catalog list contains an array of products.

My code for the catalog goes something like this:

```
public class Catalog() 
    {
     static Product[] productList;

     Catalog () {
     productList = new Product[99];
     }

     populateCatalog {
     // Assign each item product in the product array an ID, Price & Color
     }
 }
```

The productList does not change throughout the program, therefore is it bad practice to add the code from the populateCatalog method to the constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing in the constructor is fine.  Another option is just to initialize the `productList` when you declare it, like

`static Product[] productList = new Product[99];`

However....

you dont want `productList` to be static.  As it stands right now, each `Catalogue` instance does NOT have a `productList`; the class as whole has one `productList` that it shares among all instances (which is what `static` means).  It makes sense for each catalog to have its own product list right?   So change your declaration to be

`private Product[] productList;`

That way every instance of Catalog will have its own productList.

Comment: And you might want to use List<Product> instead of an array.

Comment: @Puce, its a good point, but the question is more about the constructor...still updated my answer

Comment: @Puce Good call. Would allow you to use `Collections.unmodifiableList` too for real immutability.

Comment: I'm not sure I even need any instance of catalog. The rest of the program simply references certain items from the Catalog (such as getting a product of a certain ID. If it is not static, then I need to create an instance of the class each time I need to access it right?

Comment: I think that's getting ahead of the question.  This is about constructors; we are introducing Collections, generics, immutable, etc -- all that stuff comes later.  besides, arrays are perfectly legit data structures

Comment: @Puce: It's a homework. I don't think using `List` instead of `array` is a good advice here.

Comment: List are not much more complex than arrays, but they are type safe and can grow if needed. I recommend using Lists over arrays most of the time, and when learning it's a good thing to use the recommended structures as early as possible, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

If you can initialize every `productList` element at constructor time, I'd say it would actually be best practice to do so instead of exposing a method that can later be called again. Objects that are completed at construction time and later don't change are more reliable in their use and inherently thread-safe. The term is "immutable", although I'm not entirely certain it'd apply in this case.

Comment: That's kind of what I had in mind, but it I was a bit unsure about stuffing too much code in there.

Comment: If it belongs there, why not? Alternatively, you could partition the code into private methods, but that only makes sense if there'd be multiple constructors to use them and/or some of the methods are reusable. There's also [instance initializer blocks](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), but they're rarely used and you'd probably better focus on more essential stuff now.

Comment: This answer is "double-plus good."  And if a constructor ends up with too much code in it, I will typically extract code to private static methods (called from the constructor).

Answer (score 1):

Populating the Catalog array in constructor is not something that is prohibited by any guideline. It depends upon if the process to populate is a long one to complete or not. Also , it is recommended to populate it in the constructor because that way you are always sure of having your catalog object properly constructed before external code sees it. If its done in a separate method , your client code may forget to call it before starting to use it and that could lead to problems.

Answer (score 1):

If productList *must* be static, you want to do it like this:

```
public class Catalog() {
     public static Product[] productList;

     static {
         productList = new Product[99];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been known to do this:

```
public class Catalog {
  static Product[] productList = { //
  //
      new Product(1, "one"), //
      new Product(2, "two"), //
      // ...
      new Product(99, "99th"), //
  };
}
```

*(The line comments are there to keep my IDE's auto-formatter from making it unreadable.)*